# Hugo - Shortcode - Modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown, hugo

I am using Hugo version 0.74

I have built a shortcode which is :

1. Create a button with text that I specify
2. Opens a modal window which consists of getform.io

Everything works fine, expect for one small glitch:

**I have to hit the button twice for it to open the modal window**

I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox and Edge and everywhere I need to click twice for it to open it.

Where am I going wrong ?

```
{{$text := .Get "text"}}


<button id="id_reachout" style="background:#28A745;color:white;font-family: 'Varela Round';" onClick="showModal();"> {{$text}}   </button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal-column" style="border: 5px double red">
                <img src="/img/MyModal.png" alt="Alternate text" class="modal-image">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-column">
                <form action="https://getform.io/f/4804d94b-8f1q-4a05-a679-7da0ba070952" method="POST">
                    <label for="id_name" class="modal-label"> Name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" class="modal-input">
                    <label for="id_email" class="modal-label"> Email </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" class="modal-input">
                    <label for="id_message" class="modal-label"> Message </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="id_message" class="modal-textarea"> </textarea>
                    <input id="id_submit" class="modal-submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my MyArticle.md file , I call this shortcode as follows :

```
{{<modal_button text="I have some more questions related to assets!">}}
```

My custom.js file is :

```
function showModal() {

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("id_reachout");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is my css file :

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    display:block;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto; /* 5% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    height: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.modal-label {
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.modal-input {
    width: 439px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .modal-input:focus {
        border: 2px solid #5DADE2;
    }

.modal-textarea {
    width: 439px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-submit {
    width: 439px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit {
    width: 127px;
    height: 60px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    #submit:hover {
        opacity: .9;
    }

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.modal-column {
    flex:50%;
    padding:10px;
}

.left-column{
    font-size:2rem;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `showModal()` when the user clicks the button. However that function adds *another* `onclick = function` - which is requiring users to click twice.

`showModal()` should immediately invoke the logic for showing the modal, rather than attaching another `onclick` function.

**Quick fix:**

Replace:

```js
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

With:

```js
if (modal.style.display != "block") {
   modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ntq29wj6/)** - you could omit the `if` check if you want and simply replace the `onclick` with `modal.style.display = "block";` if you wish.

```js
function showModal() {

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("id_reachout");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    if (modal.style.display != "block") {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    display:block;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto; /* 5% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    height: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.modal-label {
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.modal-input {
    width: 439px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .modal-input:focus {
        border: 2px solid #5DADE2;
    }

.modal-textarea {
    width: 439px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-submit {
    width: 439px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit {
    width: 127px;
    height: 60px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    #submit:hover {
        opacity: .9;
    }

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.modal-column {
    flex:50%;
    padding:10px;
}

.left-column{
    font-size:2rem;

}
```

```html
<button id="id_reachout" style="background:#28A745;color:white;font-family: 'Varela Round';" onClick="showModal();"> {{$text}}   </button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal-column" style="border: 5px double red">
                <img src="/img/MyModal.png" alt="Alternate text" class="modal-image">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-column">
                <form action="https://getform.io/f/4804d94b-8f1q-4a05-a679-7da0ba070952" method="POST">
                    <label for="id_name" class="modal-label"> Name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" class="modal-input">
                    <label for="id_email" class="modal-label"> Email </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" class="modal-input">
                    <label for="id_message" class="modal-label"> Message </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="id_message" class="modal-textarea"> </textarea>
                    <input id="id_submit" class="modal-submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your quick response. It helped me think in the right direction. I made the following changes :  1. Removed extraneous code in showModal() 2. Added a close window function .  I tried your code exactly and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Mani glad to hear you figured it out - yeah, the main problem was adding the `onclick` after the click - I'm surprised the code change I suggested didn't work, it worked in the demo. Maybe there's some code on your local machine that wasn't present in the demo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Justin. It pointed me to the right direction and the below code fixed the problem :

```
function showModal() {

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    modal.style.display = "block";
}

/* Added a close Modal */

function closeModal() {

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "none";

}
```

In the html, I made just a small change in span - I added an onClick=closeModal() :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" onclick="closeModal();">&times;</span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal-column" style="border: 5px double red">
                <img src="/img/PlanyourmoneyModal.png" alt="Financial Planning, Goal Planning" class="modal-image">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-column">
                <form action="https://getform.io/f/4804d94b-8f1b-4a05-a679-7da0ba070952" method="POST">
                    <label for="id_name" class="modal-label"> Name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" class="modal-input">
                    <label for="id_email" class="modal-label"> Email </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" class="modal-input">
                    <label for="id_message" class="modal-label"> Message </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="id_message" class="modal-textarea"> </textarea>
                    <input id="id_submit" class="modal-submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```